# Is "abreast a" something ever correct?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Quick question about the correct use of "abreast". I have noticed most of the example sentences online only use "abreast of" and I am wondering if using "abreast a" instead is ever correct grammatically?

Eg 1: He fell abreast of the door.

Eg 2: He fell abreast a door.

The intention here is simply to indicate that a person is alongside a door. I prefer 2 since it is shorter and the meaning is still clear, but is it grammatically correct?

Comment: If abreast meant alongside, okay. Does it?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, 1. appears to suggest so: https://www.dictionary.com/browse/abreast

Comment: @FrontEnd You seem to be asking whether it can be used as a preposition, but that definition says "adverb, adjective". Have you looked up the word to see whether it can be a preposition?

Comment: One person alone can't be abreast of anything, surely?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22abreast+a%22 - Lots of examples here

Comment: I suggest 'He fell abreast a door' could never be as acceptable as 'He fell abreast the door' but why are you Asking? Is this for a writing project, from pure curiosity or what?

Comment: The question asks about "abreast a", but the "a" is fairly irrelevant, what matters is the absence of "of". Even in your given example, you switch from "the" to "a" for no discernible reason. Do you somehow exclude "He fell abreast _the_ door" from "He fell abreast _a_ door" in terms of what you allegedly consider to be correct?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: I don't see why the (in)definite article distinction matters here. I would expect that the answer whether one case is correct inherently also answers the other case.

Comment: Sorry Flater I shouldn't have gone so far sideways with what is really a point of style, not grammar. 'Exclude' isn't the right term but I did mean to distinguish or separate 
"… abreast the… " from "… abreast a door". That's about context and juxtaposition, not grammar so if it really doesn't work for you, feel free to Ask about in Chat, or in SE Writing.

Comment: @Richard all the ones I looked at were multiple things being abreast. IMO the sentence is incorrect not by any grammatical rule, but by the meaning of "abreast".

Answer (score 18):

Rare, but there are examples in the Corpus of Contemporary American English.

> "This must be the outskirts of Leiden," my mother says as we come
> **abreast an old stone windmill**. (Southwest Review;  2002, Vol. 87 Issue
> 2/3;      Taber, Sara Mansfield)
>
> As they draw **abreast another door** John suddenly jumps sideways, knocking Bobbi and Jack through the door ahead of him! (Hellraiser: Bloodline; 1996)

A few hits in HANSARD with the most recent from 1913.

> she had to wait until flood tide in order that her bow would be
> brought **abreast the harbour** and she could steam out (English
> Parliament - House of Commons; 1913)

A google search of *abreast a/an/another* produces a few hits, mostly dated and found in official documents or nautical texts.

> No person may operate a narrow track vehicle in a single lane **abreast
> another motorcycle** or narrow track vehicle ([wa.gov](https://app.leg.wa.gov/committeeschedules/Home/Document/137193))
>
> Five more black beacons mark the edge of the western bank as it trends
> further to the westward , the last of the five being just **abreast a
> red buoy** on the opposite side of the channel at the Flats. (Pugh's
> Queensland Almanac, Law Calendar, Directory, Coast Guide and
> Gazetteer; Brisbane, Australia. Theophills P. Pugh, 1885)
>
> Anchorage can be made in the middle of the bay , in 10 fathoms , a little over 600 yards above Astronomical Point at the entrance and **abreast a rocky point** at the north end of the sand beach on the west side (British Columbia Pilot: The coast of British Columbia from...; 1916)

Grammatically, it seems similar constructions have been used; however, it would be unusual, with the *abreast of...* variation being several orders of magnitude more common, and may not be appropriate in context.

Comment: How refreshing, an answer based on empirical evidence! +1

Comment: Do we even need a bunch of specific "curated corpus" examples? [Here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22keep+abreast+the+times%22&sca_esv=560476944&tbm=bks&ei=_TDrZLjIINulhbIPq-uQuAk&start=130&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwj4uqLi2_yAAxXbUkEAHas1BJc4jAEQ8dMDegQIAhAC&biw=1638&bih=754&dpr=2.5) is a link to page 14 of my search in Google Books for just the specific prepositionless usage ***keep abreast the times***, with 10 published written instances on every page. It would be perverse to label the usage "invalid" when it occurs so often, even though it's obviously far from the "preferred" form.

Comment: We have to be careful about how ngrams are used to support answers about usage. If **abreast the X** is how the word is used primarily in military and nautical contexts, and such contexts are infrequent compared to other contexts, we should not leap to the conclusion that "abreast the..." is moribund.  Notice the phrase "draw abreast" in the *Hellraiser* quote. **draw abreast** is a nautical phrase. Whether it's an appropriate stylistic choice there is a separate question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It seems relevant how versatile a construction this is - is it simply a surviving idiom? what year do those examples come from? Of course the asker could do their own extensive research, but then why come here? Clearly the typical references didn't suffice, as the question points out. Also, your examples have the definite article, something the asker did not include in their question. It would seem insufficient to summarily dismiss the question on this basis.

Comment: I'm not a great one for terminology, but I wouldn't argue with google Bard, which tells me *In the phrase "keep abreast of," the word "abreast" is used as a preposition.* Obviously "of" is another preposition, and in addition to the many contexts where ***a*** preposition is optional in English, there are (far more?) contexts with ***two consecutive prepositions***, one or both of which can be removed without necessarily affecting the meaning. So even if you've never actually encountered "abreast" not followed by "of", you might reasonably guess that it would be at least an "acceptable" usage.

Comment: ...I think the question would be fine on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), but it's a bit out of place here.

Comment: I think the question rather too advanced and subtle for ELL.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Reasonably guess? In fact there are many prepositions that occur in pairs where the second preposition _of_ preceding an NP complement is not optional in standard English: _irrespective of, because of, ahead of_, _instead of, regardless of, east of, north of, south of, west of_ to name a few. Could we reasonably guess that leaving off the _of_ would be at least an "acceptable" usage for these?

Comment: I don't recognize *irrespective, because, instead, regardless, east...* as "prepositions" (nor does the OED). Interestingly, as well as ***abreast***, I see the OED says ***ahead*** can be a preposition, and I have to say I've no real problem with discarding the *second* preposition in [*We introduced bonded porce dentistry in 1983 , **well ahead the competition,***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22well+ahead+the+competition%22) so *that* might be an interesting avenue to explore. But ELU isn't here to teach English to nns, which appears to be your goal.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'll stick to modern reference grammars for my part of speech tags, thanks. And I'm not sure the asker would appreciate the 'nn' label you've bestowed on them. I've no idea how my providing a few examples of actual usage and pointing out how rare they are has created this much of a stir, but if it's this worth this degree of debate, surely EL&U can accommodate this question.

Comment: I think it's an ELL question, but you think it's okay on ELU. Let's just leave it at that.

Comment: Ignoring empiricism... In 65 years on this earth, the first half in Canada (Quebec) and the second in the US (New England and Texas), I've really only heard _abreast_ in nautical situations, or in sentences that alluded to nautical situations.  The motorcycle example (in an official document) also sounds right as well.  I'd look funny at anyone who described themselves, or others, as either _abreast a door_ or _abreast of a door_ - though the former sounds a little better.

Answer (score 2):

As a general purpose note, never be surprised when you hear "a" instead of *of* (or, especially after /d/ or /t/, instead of *to* or *do*). Any verb or construction that ends in *of* (as well as those that end in *have*) ends in a /v/ sound, and if that's followed by almost any consonant, it tends to disappear; how many English words begin with V plus a consonant, like *Vlad*? Take away the /v/ from *of* and *have* and all you got left is /ə/, that is, "a".

That gives us such spelling pronunciations as

- *alla those guys, a lotta them, abreasta them, on toppa them, woulda, coulda, shoulda, musta*

And the substitutions for *to* give us

- *wanna, gotta, useta, hafta*

as well.

These are not the correct spellings (unless you're transcribing dialog), but they are the spellings (often called "eye dialect") that represent correct American English speech, which,  as we all know, the standard (aka "correct") spelling doesn't.

Comment: While this is true, it’s clearly not what the question is referring to. Considering _a_ an eye-spelling for _of_ would make the example given, “*He fell abreast of door”, and you wouldn’t need to ask an ELU question to know that’s very obviously ungrammatical.